# jQuery function does not start on loading page

Tags: jquery

I have this script in my page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).idleTimeout({
        inactivity: 30000,
        noconfirm: 10000,
        sessionAlive: 10000
    });
});
```

But it generates error, and i can't understand why. Error is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'idleTimeout'
```

I'm using `jQuery` : `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for help, it was typo in script source path.

Comment: it means that the plugin `idleTimeout` is missing from the page

Comment: Have you linked the idleTimeout plugin?

Comment: yeas it is included in header too: 
`echo "<script src=\"/includes/ui/flat/js/plugins/timeut/jquery-idleTimeout.js\"></script>\n";`

Comment: Did you added a link `<script src>` to your head? the `idleTimeout` plugin is missing.

Comment: Whut, why echoïng in the head of a html page?

Comment: Thanks for help, it was typo in src path. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

idleTimeout is not a jQuery default function you need to download this plugin

[**idleTimeout**](https://github.com/philpalmieri/jquery-idleTimeout)

Comment: I have included it in my header

Comment: Are you sure it is linked correctly? Could you edit your question and show how you've included it

Comment: If it wont be found, then it will be marked as red in Inspect element window in browser, not it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Simple include your `idleTimeout` plugin js

```
<html>
<head>
      <script src="includes/ui/flat/js/plugins/timeut/jquery-idleTimeout.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw the project on github and the example page is using [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) as well.

Have you put it in your header? 
Have you put it just after your jquery-1.10.2.min.js?

Comment: No wories. Everything is ok now. That was just a bad source path name. Thanx!